# Woocommerce stripe guest checkout is not working

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, stripe-payments

Order is only getting placed when admin is logged in but without login, the order didn't get placed.
I have already tried to change the setup of plugin but what i found out is even if i try to change the settings the order is still not getting placed without loggin in as admin

Comment: Yes even any payment method requires at-least one email address. you have to setup stripe form with email field, and payment fields. But first check how guest checkout is possible in woocommerce.

Comment: my stripe form has an email field and i have allowed guest checkout in woocommerce